# How to find & uninstall the patch [msp] installed in a machine?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, patch, msp

I have created patch [msp] using installsheild.

At that time i was not aware of that option

> "Allow Patch to be uninstalled "

Now that patch has to be uninstalled.

I am having that msp file with me.[I open the msp using orca and check for product GUID but it was not there]

Which information can be used to find & uninstall the msp already installed in a machine?

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the target product codes this patch can be applied to, open Orca and select `View -> Summary Information...` in the main menu. In the dialog that pops up you can find what you're looking for:

[image]

However, I don't think you'll be able to uninstall the patch itself if it was set as not uninstallable. It seems you'll have to uninstall the product itself, or follow the major upgrade strategy to replace it with the proper (probably, already upgraded) version.

Comment: As i can't uninstall it , Is deleting the uninstall registry key would allow to install next patch with same or lower version?

Comment: I suppose that if you remove all the traces of that patch from the target machine, it will be possible. But I'm not sure I can find all of them...